# sending location coordinates using FCM

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

I made a chat application using firebase between two android devices it works fine multiple client can sign in to the same room and chat .
i want to add a gps activity to my code so as one user send the word gps the other user would send its location every 5 seconds just keep sending it .
the idea is putting a condition on the received messages if it carries the word "GPS" keep sending the location how can i do this with my chat code

Main Activity::

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText roomname;
    Button join;
    ListView roomlist;
    ArrayList<String> roomarraylist; // to store rooms list
    ArrayAdapter<String>  roomadapter;

    DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    public String username;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        roomname=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        join=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);

        roomlist=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.roomlistview);
        roomarraylist=new ArrayList<String>();
        roomadapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,roomarraylist);

        roomlist.setAdapter(roomadapter);

        databaseReference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().getRoot();

        request_username();
        join.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Map<String,Object> map=new HashMap<String, Object>();
                map.put(roomname.getText().toString(),"");
                databaseReference.updateChildren(map);
            }
        });
        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Iterator iterator =dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator();
                Set<String> set=new HashSet<String>();

                while (iterator.hasNext()){
                    // GET NAMES OF ALL ROOMS ONE BY ONE FROM  DATABASE
                    set.add((String) ( (DataSnapshot)iterator.next()).getKey());
                }
                roomarraylist.clear();
                roomarraylist.addAll(set);

                roomadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

        roomlist.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Chat_room.class);
                intent.putExtra("Room_Name",((TextView)view).getText().toString());
                intent.putExtra("UserName",username);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    private void request_username() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Please Enter your Name");
        final EditText edittext=new EditText(this);
        builder.setView(edittext);
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                username=edittext.getText().toString();
                if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(username)){

                }
                else{
                    request_username();
                }
            }
        }).setNegativeButton("Quit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
                request_username();
            }
        });

        builder.show();
    }
}
```

Chat_room class::

```
public class Chat_room extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btnsend;
    TextView recievedmsg;
    EditText editmsg;

    DatabaseReference rootRoomName;

    String roomname;
    String username;
    private String chatusername;
    private String chatmessage;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat_room);
        btnsend=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnsend);
        recievedmsg=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.recievedmsg);
        editmsg=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editmsg);

        roomname=getIntent().getExtras().get("Room_Name").toString();
        username=getIntent().getExtras().get("UserName").toString();

        setTitle(roomname);
        rootRoomName= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().getRoot().child(roomname);

        btnsend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                DatabaseReference childRoot=rootRoomName.push();
                Map<String,Object> map=new HashMap<String, Object>();

                map.put("Name",username);
                map.put("message",editmsg.getText().toString());

                childRoot.updateChildren(map);

            }
        });

        rootRoomName.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                update_message(dataSnapshot);
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                update_message(dataSnapshot);
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void update_message(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        chatusername=(String)dataSnapshot.child("Name").getValue();
        chatmessage=(String)dataSnapshot.child("message").getValue();

        recievedmsg.append(chatusername + ":" + chatmessage + "\n\n");
    }
}
```

the GPS Activity ::

```
public class Gps extends AppCompatActivity implements ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {
    TextView x;
    TextView y;
    LocationRequest LR;
    private GoogleApiClient GAC;
    String lat;
    String Lon;
    //public  String lat="Latitude";
    //public  String lon="Longitude";

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        createLocationRequest();
        startLocationUpdates();
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        Location Location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(GAC);
        if (Location != null) {
            Double Lat = Location.getLatitude();
            Double lon = Location.getLongitude();
            x = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
            y = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            x.setText("Ltitude is " + String.valueOf(Lat));
            y.setText("Longitude is " + String.valueOf(lon));

        }


    }


    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (GAC != null) {
            GAC.connect();
        }
    }

    @Override

    protected void onStop() {
        GAC.disconnect();
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "the connection suspended", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {

        Toast.makeText(this, "the connection failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        x = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        y = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        x.setText("latitude is " + String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()));
        y.setText("longitude is " + String.valueOf(location.getLongitude()));
    }

    protected void createLocationRequest() {
        LR = new LocationRequest();
        LR.setInterval(5000);
        LR.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    }

    protected void startLocationUpdates() {

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            return;
        }
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                GAC, LR, (this));

    }


    protected void build_GAC() {
        GAC = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();

    }



    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gps);
        build_GAC();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is too late answer but anyhow I will mention it here.

If you have subscribed to a Topic (my assumption), then you just need to send a POST request to that topic.

Here is the code that I had written to achieve same functionality as you have asked for.

```
URL fireBaseUrl = new URL("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send");
            HttpsURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) fireBaseUrl.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10000);
            urlConnection.addRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            urlConnection.addRequestProperty("Authorization", "key=" + NetworkUtils.SERVER_KEY); // Paste your server key here
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

            JSONObject notification = new JSONObject()
                    .put("to", "/topics/skm") // Your topic here
                    .put("data", new JSONObject()
                            .put("latitude", longitude)
                            .put("longitude", latitude));

            OutputStreamWriter oStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(urlConnection.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8");
            String requestString = notification.toString();
            Log.d("JSON REQUEST", requestString);

            oStreamWriter.write(requestString);
            oStreamWriter.close();

            int status = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
            Log.d("STATUS CODE", status + "");


            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder responseBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            String readLine;

            while ((readLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                responseBuilder.append(readLine);
            }

            response = responseBuilder.toString();

            Log.d("RESPONSE", response);
```

That's it. I hope you will be able to receive Lat/Long on client side.